# NodeJS http.get quit my app

Tags: node.js, http, get

I have a werd problem. When i am running this code to get a image, but some images make this line quit my program. I dont get any error and i dont know how to debug the problem.

```
http.get(obj.image.url.split("?")[0], function (getResponse){
    var chunks = [];
    getResponse.on('data', function (chunk){
        chunks.push(chunk);
    }).on('end', function(){
        if(getResponse.statusCode == 200){
            var buffer = Buffer.concat(chunks);
            obj.image = {
                url: obj.image.url,
                width: sizeOf(buffer).width,
                height: sizeOf(buffer).height
            }
            callback(obj);
        }
    });
});
```

I try to put a console.log in every step in that function, but nothing i triggering after http.get...

http://static.feber.se/article_images/38/68/15/386815_1280.jpg - WORKS
https://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2015/02/crunchweek-4-3.jpg - FAIL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have to deal with for the different protocols `http://` and `https://`. It seems there's nothing built-in for `node.js`. You may use modules like [request](https://github.com/request/request) or [needle](https://github.com/tomas/needle) instead. They will figure out which protocol to use, and how to handle redirects (if required) and such.

Answer (score 1):

The image that's failing is from an HTTPS link. If you are connecting to HTTPS you should use the proper NodeJS class. Its useage is very similar. Checkout the documentation for more info: https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_get_options_callback